# xlswrite precision matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a 2D array of double values. for example;

```
0.6074    0.1388    0.6711
0.9967    0.2230    0.7232
0.0424    0.5830    0.5044
```

I need to write it in an Excel file with '%2.2f' format like the following

```
0.61    0.14    0.67
1.00    0.22    0.72
0.04    0.58    0.50
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could just round off:

```
round(My2dArray .* 100)./100
```